# H2DBでのパスワード暗号化、復号化の方法

Tags: sql, encryption

H2DBでフォームから入力したパスワードの暗号化と復号化のSQLを教えていただきたいです。

```
insert into table(user_name, user_pass) values (?, crypt(?, gen_salt('bf')))
```

また、cryptを使うことはできないのですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crypt`, `gen_salt` で検索したところ [PostgreSQLのリファレンス](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/11/html/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.34.6)がヒットしたので、PostgreSQLの該当関数に相当するH2DBの関数は何か、という質問だとして回答しますと:

- 上のリンク先にある通り、`crypt`は(暗号化関数ではなく)ハッシュ関数なので復号はできません。
- H2DBの備えるハッシュ関数として [`hash`](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#hash)があります。リンク先例文の通りパスワード格納も想定した関数だとは思いますが、PostgreSQLのものとは大きく仕様が異なります。
- `crypt` はPostgreSQL独自の関数なので他のDBMSでは利用できません(過去のMySQL [`encrypt`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt)のように似たものを備えるDBMSもあるようですが)。

---

production環境ではPostgreSQLを、development環境ではH2DBを、というようなことを考えられているのであれば、DBMSの機能でなくプログラミング言語/フレームワークの機能でハッシュ化するのも一案かと考えます。要は、DBMS依存を排除する、ということです。

---

Spring Boot であれば、Spring Security の [`PasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jc-authentication.html#core-services-password-encoding) を利用するのが一般的かと思います。

依存関係を追加し、

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Bean定義を行えば、

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

インジェクションして利用できます。

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

...
    final String password = passwordEncoder.encode("mypassword");
```

[サンプルコード](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/blob/master/so60223/src/main/java/com/example/passwordencodersample/PasswordEncoderSampleApplication.java)

Comment: ありがとうございます。spring boot h2でシステム開発をしている学生であり、spring bootのハッシュ化が複雑に思えたため、質問いたしました。回答ありがとうございます。